# Unexpected results with OpenSSL DES encryption

Tags: openssl

I learned the DES algorithm by reading [this article](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~kant/teaching/hess/krypto-ws2006/des.htm) but I get different results when using the same example with OpenSSL.

In this article, we see that `0123456789ABCDEF` is encrypted to `85E813540F0AB405` using the key `133457799BBCDFF1`. I believe this uses ECB mode but I think it does not matter here because there is only one block.

I tried to get the same result with OpenSSL, by running:

```
openssl enc -nosalt -nopad -des-ecb -in test -out test.des -pass file:password
```

But I get the following result in `test.des`: `C0C9742DCEB936`.

The content of `test` is exactly `0123456789ABEF` and the content of `password` is exactly `133457799BBCDFF1` (in binary form, edited with `hexedit`).

So why do I get a different result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the expected content:

```
openssl enc -des-ecb -in test -out test.des -nosalt -nopad -K 133457799BBCDFF1
```

I don't know what is the difference between `-K` and `-pass`, though.